# Installing Git 2.9.0 on windows 8.1

Tags: git

When I'm trying to install git on windows, it will ask for extra configuration options as in this picture.

[image]

So, if I check them as it is is there any consequences?

Comment: You get extra performance and the credential manager. Want sort of consequences are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

its some new improvements made to git.

Its adding new flags to your config:

> ***`core.fscache`***
>       Enable additional caching of file system data for some operations.
>
> File system data will be read in bulk and cached in memory for certain operations (`core.fscache` is set to `true`).
>
> **This provides a significant performance boost (experimental).**

Since git v2.0 GITHUB is maintaining the windows installer and they added it to the distribution.

> The Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM) **provides secure Git credential storage for Windows**.
>
> It's the successor to the Windows Credential Store for Git (git-credential-winstore), which is no longer maintained.
>
> Compared to Git's built-in credential storage for Windows (wincred), which provides single-factor authentication support working on any HTTP enabled Git repository, **GCM provides multi-factor authentication support** for Visual Studio Team Services, Team Foundation Server, and GitHub